# Open emacs through variable with different color

Tags: linux, variables, ubuntu, emacs, colors

I want to open emacs using a variable, but I want letters color to be set as red(for example).

So far I did this:

```
TEXT_EDITOR=emacs" "--fg" "red
```

And than I open it with:

```
$TEXT_EDITOR
```

Problem here is, when emacs opens using this variable, letters have default color, they are still black.

I've got error when emacs opens, containing message:

```
"uknown option '--fg'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the option is `-fg`, not `--fg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Sorry for the trouble.

Right thing to do was:

> TEXT_EDITOR=emacs" "'-fg'" "'red'

Thanks for help.